# Inserting string in another string at specific index c++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, stdstring, qstring

I have a `QString` (it may does not matter since I convet it to std::string anyway) which contains the full unix path to a file. e.g. `/home/user/folder/name.of.another_file.txt`.

I want to append another string to this file name right before the extension name. e.g. I pass to the function "positive", here I call it `vector_name` and at the end I want to get `/home/user/folder/name.of.another_file_positive.txt` (note that the last underscore should be added by the function itself.

Here is my code but it does not compile, unfortunately!!

```
QString temp(mPath); //copy value of the member variable so it doesnt change???

std::string fullPath = temp.toStdString();
std::size_t lastIndex = std::string::find_last_of(fullPath, ".");
std::string::insert(lastIndex, fullPath.append("_" + vector_name.toStdString()));

std::cout << fullPath;
```

I get the following errors:

```
error: cannot call member function 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::find_last_of(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]' without object
         std::size_t lastIndex = std::string::find_last_of(fullPath, ".");

cannot call member function 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]' without object
     std::string::insert(lastIndex, fullPath.append("_" + vector_name.toStdString()));
```

P.S. I would really appriciate if you also can tell me how can I achieve this using QString or Qt library itself!

Comment: How about `std::size_t lastIndex = full_path.find_last_of(".");`? It's a member function not a static function. Same goes for `insert`.

Comment: QString also has [lastIndexOf](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#lastIndexOf-1), [append](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#append) and [insert](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#insert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `find_last_of` and `insert` are member functions of `std::string`, not static or non-member functions.  Therefore you need an object to access the function.

The corrections are below:

```
std::size_t lastIndex = fullPath.find_last_of(".");
fullPath.insert(lastIndex, "_" + vector_name.toStdString());
cout << fullPath;
```

[Live Example using dummy data](http://ideone.com/YPQ0SF)

Also, you may want to test the return values of those function calls.  What if there is no `"."` in the file name?